# Estimate related to linear transport equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes, transport-equation

Suppose the conditions:

$1)$ $p \in [1,+\infty]$ ,

$2)$ $u_{0}(x) \in L^{p}(\mathbb{R^{N}})$,

$3)$ $c + \mbox{div} b \in L^{1}([0,T];L^{q}_{\mbox{loc}}(\mathbb{R^{N}}))$, $b \in L^{1}([0,T];(L^{q}_{\mbox{loc}}(\mathbb{R^{N}}))^{N})$, where $q$ is the conjugate exponent of $p$,

$4)$ $b \in L^{1}([0,T];(L^{1}_{\mbox{loc}}(\mathbb{R^{N}}))^{N})$ and $c \in L^{1}([0,T];(L^{1}_{\mbox{loc}}(\mathbb{R^{N}}))^{N})$,

$5)$ **If** $p > 1$, assume $c + \frac{1}{p} \mbox{div} b \in L^{1}([0,T]; L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R^{N}}))$

$6)$ **If** $p = 1$, assume $c$, $\mbox{div} b \in L^{1}([0,T]; L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R^{N}}))$

hold for the linear transport equation:

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} - b \cdot \nabla_{x}u + c u = 0$ in $(0,T) \times \mathbb{R^{N}}$ ;

with the initial condition $u_{0}(x) = u(0,x) \in L^{p}(\mathbb {R^{N}})$.

Now, with this in hand how can we show,

$a)$ $||u(t)||_{\infty} \leq \mbox{C}_{0}||u_{0}||_{\infty}$ a.e. on $(0,T)$, where $\mbox{C}_{0}$ depends only on $||c||_{L^{1}([0,T];L^{\infty}(\mathbb R^{N}))}$

and

$b)$ $||u(t)||_{p} \leq \mbox{C}_{0}||u_{0}||_{p}$ a.e. on $(0,T)$ for $p < \infty$, where $\mbox{C}_{0}$ depends only on $||c + \frac{1}{p} \mbox{div} b||_{L^{1}([0,T];L^{\infty}(\mathbb R^{N}))}$

---

Now, I know in the case of Linear Transport Equation with constant coefficient (i.e. instead of $b(t,x)$, we would have $b \in \mathbb R^{N}$ only) we have explicitly:

$u(t,x) = u(0,x-tb) + \int_{0}^{t} c(x+(s-t)b,s) ds$ as the solution, from where the estimates follow.

But how to do it in the case with coefficients $b(t,x)$ instead of just $b$ ??

Thanking you,

Comment: To obtain a more explicit expression for the solution let $\eta$ denote the flow map associated to $b$, and then compute $\frac{d}{d t}u(\eta(x,t),t)$ for any solution $u$. This should help you derive a closed form expression for $u$ in terms of $b,c,\eta,u_0$, and it shouldn't be so hard to show that defining $u$ by such an expression gives you a solution. This would establish an "explicit" form of $u$ from which the desired estimates might pop out. I haven't worked through all the details yet, so this might not be the most direct way to obtain the estimates...

Comment: I do agree. But as I said, if I am not wrong, the trouble is due to the use of $b(x,t)$, instead of the use of $b$ - a given vector. So, can you be more specific ??